# Is SignalR with .NET 5 compatible with a Blazor application running .NET Standard 2.1?

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-5

Having a nightmare of a time setting up a simple Blazor SignalR application.

According to documentation, SignalR is greatly improved in .NET 5. It's not compatible with .NET Core 3.1. That's fair enough.

If I make a Blazor web assembly client, not hosted in .NET Core (I don't understand what that really means but I decided not to check the box to do it), then it runs on .NET Standard 2.1

So if I set up SignalR in .NET 5 and then try to consume it using my .NET Standard 2.1 Blazor client, would that work? If not what should I do?

--

Edit: [image]

Comment: .NET Core 5 doesn't exist, it's just .NET 5.

Comment: > If I make a Blazor web assembly client, not hosted in .NET Core , then it runs on .NET Standard 2.1.. 
If you select .net 5.0 it does not.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I don't kunderstand, I added a screenshot to show. The dropdown box says ASP.NET Core 5.0 is that different?

Comment: @BrianParker I looked up .NET Standard and it says it's an API not an implementation (for class libraries), yet my Blazor app which says .NET Standard 2.1 can run? How is that possible? I am so confused

Comment: .NET Standard cannot run, it's not an application, it's just a class library. You have 2 options: use .NET Standard 2.1 and be limited to ASP.NET Core 3.1 (due to compatibility) or use .NET Core 5

Comment: I don't understand, I have a .NET Standard 2.1 project and it literally runs. You press F5 and it opens the browser and hits localhost and renders the pages and views etc. Maybe it's different for web assembly? Either way when I made a new web assembly project it came up as .NET 5 so I don't know how I made the first one. Maybe it changed in a VS update.

Comment: You can use them all without any problem! they are all compatible.

Answer (score 1):

> If I make a Blazor web assembly client, not hosted in .NET Core (I don't understand what that really means but I decided not to check the box to do it), then it runs on .NET Standard 2.1

If you create a WASM app using **.NET Core 3.1**:

- .NET Core hosted: There will be 3 projects created:

  - `.Client` is `netstandard2.1` and using `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` SDK
  - `.Server` will be `netcoreapp3.1` and using `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` SDK
  - `.Shared` will be `netstandard2.1` and using `Microsoft.NET.Sdk` SDK
- NOT .NET Core hosted: There will be 1 project created, which is `netstandard2.1` and using `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` SDK

If you create a WASM app using **.NET 5**

- .NET Core hosted: There will be 3 projects created:

  - `.Client` is `net5.0` and using `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly` SDK
  - `.Server` is `net5.0` and using `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` SDK
  - `.Shared` is `net5.0` and using `Microsoft.NET.Sdk` SDK
- NOT .NET Core hosted: There will be 1 project created, which is `net5.0` and using `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly` SDK

> So if I set up SignalR in .NET 5 and then try to consume it using my .NET Standard 2.1 Blazor client, would that work? If not what should I do?

This should not be a problem. To avoid any further confusion you can easily upgrade your .NET Core 3.1 WASM app to .NET 5 following these steps:

On `.csproj` file:

1. Change `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">` to `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">`
2. Change `<TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>` to `<TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>`
3. Remove `<RazorLangVersion>3.0</RazorLangVersion>`
4. Remove package reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Build`
5. Update all other packages to latest stable `5.0.0`

Make sure you have these setup properly on your machine

1. Latest visual studio https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
2. .NET 5 SDK https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0